# How to put an image and a QProgressBar inside a QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing some kind of download manager and display the file name, it's size and the remaining bytes in a QTableView. Now I want to visualize the progress with a QProgressBar and display an image (to indicate whether it's an down- or upload). How can I add or display a QProgressBar and an image **inside** the QTableView?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `QTableView`, I presume you use a model linked to this view.

One solution would be to use delegates (see `QItemDelegate`) to paint the progress, In `QItemDelegate::paint` method you have to define, use `QStyle` of the widget (`widget->style()`) to paint the progress (use `QStyle::drawControl` with `QStyle::CE_ProgressBarContents` as control identifier).

Check the documentation from the example Star Delegate, to see how to define the delegate for the column you need.

**Later edit:** Example of defining the delegate paint method (code sketch, not really tested, take it as a principle, not fully working).

```
void MyDelegate::paint ( QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    QStyleOptionProgressBar progressStyle;
    progressStyle.rect = option.rect; // Maybe some other initialization from option would be needed

    // For the sake of the example, I assume that the index indicates the progress, and the next two siblings indicate the min and max of the progress.
    QModelIndex minIndex = index.sibling( index.row(), index.column() + 1);
    QModelIndex maxIndex = index.sibling( index.row(), index.column() + 2);

    progressStyle.minimum = qvariant_cast< int>( minIndex.data( Qt::UserRole));
    progressStyle.maximum = qvariant_cast< int>( maxIndex.data( Qt::UserRole));

    progressStyle.progress = qvariant_cast< int>( index.data( Qt::UserRole));
    progressStyle.textVisible = false;
    qApp->style()->drawControl( QStyle::CE_ProgressBarContents, progressStyleOption, painter);
}
```

Comment: I already looked at the Star Delegate example, but their they just paint polygons. Can you provide more information how to paint a widget inside the `QItemDelegate::paint` method?

Answer (score 2):

```
TrackDelegate::TrackDelegate(QObject *parent)
    : QItemDelegate(parent)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TrackDelegate::paint( QPainter* painter,
                           const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                           const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem  viewOption(option);
    QImage image(m_RowBackGroundImagePath);
    QPixmap pixmap(m_RowBackGroundImagePath);
    qDebug()<<"forward"<<pixmap.width()<<pixmap.height();
    pixmap.scaled(option.rect.width(),option.rect.height());
    qDebug()<<"back"<<pixmap.width()<<pixmap.height();
    qDebug()<<option.rect.width()<<option.rect.height();
    QBrush brush(pixmap);
    painter->save();
    painter->fillRect(option.rect, brush/*QColor(238, 233, 233, 255)*/);
    painter->restore();
    viewOption.rect = QRect(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), option.rect.width(), option.rect.height());
    // viewOption.palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, QColor(Qt::red));
    // viewOption.palette.setBrush ( QPalette::ButtonText, brush1);
    QItemDelegate::paint(painter, viewOption,index);

    int progress = index.model()->data(index,Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();
    QStyleOptionProgressBar progressBarOption;
    progressBarOption.rect = QRect(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y()+(SETHEIGHT - PROGRESSBARHEIGHT)/2, option.rect.width(), /*option.rect.height()*/PROGRESSBARHEIGHT);

    //qDebug()<<progressBarOption.rect.x()<<progressBarOption.rect.y()<<progressBarOption.rect.height()<<progressBarOption.rect.width();
    //qDebug()<<option.rect.x()<<option.rect.y()<<option.rect.height()<<option.rect.width();

    progressBarOption.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
    progressBarOption.direction = QApplication::layoutDirection();
    progressBarOption.fontMetrics = QApplication::fontMetrics();
    progressBarOption.minimum = 0;
    progressBarOption.maximum = 100;
    progressBarOption.textAlignment = Qt::AlignCenter;
    progressBarOption.textVisible = true;
    progressBarOption.progress = progress < 0 ? 0 : progress;
    progressBarOption.text = QString().sprintf("%d%%", progressBarOption.progress);
    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ProgressBar, &progressBarOption, painter);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use QTableWidget for this. It has a method which allows you to add widgets like a QProgressBar. It's the "setCellWidget" method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slot in QProgressBar called [setValue(int)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qprogressbar.html#value-prop),
You can update it sending a signal to this progress bar from Your file manager.
This one should be designed in a way it could check or monitor download state and sends those signals periodically.

Good approach to manage up/down/finish images would be to have additional column in table with the image item.
It would be quite easy to update your image if the socket/connection/file corrupt state would change.

Writing any example would be actually writing you a program, so i suggest to post parts of the problems (if any) with code performed by yourself.

Comment: Yep I know that, the question is how to display the progress bar *inside* the TableView. I'll write the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

`QTableView` is not for displaying widgets in a layout. Use `QGridLayout` or some other suitable layout and put the widgets in that layout.

Comment: why not use table? if the downloader has 100** files to manage this is good solution...  Like in Opera download manager for instance or any other browser. Many features for free, sorting, filtering...

Comment: You are right, I read the question hastily and though he was going to use a QTableView to lay out UI items à la HTML... it's probably fine for this kind of use.